# Drupal 7 cannot use ckeditor with IMCE to browser file on IE 11

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I try to use the ckeditor with IMCE to upload the image on IE 11, however, it show permission denied when I browser file, I have tested on chrome and firefox, it all work, does anyone know why??

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bug / incompatibility report for ckeditor, and should be reported in project's issue queue, not here.